# How can I start automatic Logstash,filebeat, metricbeat, redis, stunnel in RHEL 7

Tags: scripting, kibana

i am new to shell scripting.
I need to write a script where i need to start following processes while startup of the Linux server.Below are the processes
logstash, filebeat, metricbeat, redis, stunnel

What is the location to place the script so in order to run it while booting of Linux server.is it etc/init.d?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

To run a script at boot, you need to place your script in ‘/etc/rc.local’  file with absolute path and name of your created script after the sh command. Also, make sure that the script is executable. For example,

sh ‘/path/to/your/script’

Also, in RHEL 7, there is a command to start any service at boot.
Command:

```
systemctl enable <service-name>
```

This will start the service at boot.

Comment: I want a script which runs automatically at boot. The command 'systemctl' is used manually to start a service when I login to the server. Suppose I kept the script(myscript) in /etc/rc.local so after 'sh' in place of ‘/path/to/your/script’, I will put /etc/rc.local/myscript??

Comment: /etc/rc.local is a file. So keep your script anywhere on a server and only write absolute path of script after 'sh' in /etc/rc.local. You can follow this link https://gopukrish.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/run-a-script-at-boot-time-in-centos-7/